# Disable mat icon into mat-tree-node

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need the answer to this question: is it possible to disable a mat-icon within a mat-tree-node?

So let me show you my code. Seeing the present mat-tree-node:

```
 <mat-tree [dataSource]="ListView" [treeControl]="treeControl">
 <mat-tree-node
                *matTreeNodeDef="let node"
                matTreeNodePadding
                matTreeNodePaddingIndent="20"
                class="mat-tree-node node-level-last hover"
            >
                <button class="cursor-default" mat-icon-button disableRipple="true"></button>
                <div class="zone-action">
                <div > {{ node.item.name }} </div> 

                    <div class="icon-hover" *ngIf="!node.item.CanVisualize">

                        <div *ngIf="isEnabled">
                           <mat-icon
                                svgIcon="pencil"
                                color="primary"
                                (click)="actionReport(node.item, 'update'); $event.stopPropagation()"
                            ></mat-icon>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-tree-node>
```

I would like to have access to a list openened by the selection of a mat-tree-node, but I can't for the moment. So you have the property-binding " {{ node.item.name }} " that displays an information relative to the object selected which you need to know so as to proceed into the navigation of the component and it is needed to disable or hide the mat-icon inside `<div *ngIf="isEnabled">`.

But adding a structural directive like an ng-if in the HTML parent Node erase the node.item.name, printing an empty field, which behavior is clearly not the one searched.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion

```
  <button mat-icon-button ngIf="isEnabled" (click)="actionReport(node.item, 'update'); $event.stopPropagation()">
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <button mat-icon-button ngIf="!isEnabled" disabled>
    <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

https://material.angular.io/components/button/examples

Comment: I already tried changing div into button and it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the value of isEnabled wich seems to be undefined so maybe the problem doesn't come from that in fact... Sorry for wasting your time with that.

Comment: You can bind to the `disabled` input instead. You don't have to use a `*ngIf`. (And even then, your answer won't work as you need an asterisk behind `ngIf`.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use a `<button mat-icon-button>` instead of the `<mat-icon>` directive:

```html
<button mat-icon-button (click)="onButtonClick()">
  <mat-icon>pencil</mat-icon>
</button>
```

vs

```html
<mat-icon (click)="onButtonClick()">pencil</mat-icon>
```

Secondly, you can use the `disabled` input that the `MatButton` class (essentially a directive for `button[mat-*-button]`) exposes:

```html
<button mat-icon-button [disabled]="isEnabled">
  <mat-icon svgIcon="pencil"></mat-icon>
</button>
```

Note that the `<mat-icon>` directive does not support the `disabled` input.